# Catch firebase user creation exception

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, try-catch

Im teaching myself to program and Im building a simple spend tracker using react native expo and firebase. Im trying to catch an error that firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword throws when someone tries to sign up with a email thats already been used. Basically what I'd like to have happen is if the user creation throws an error, give user some sort of notification and do not navigate to "Home".

This is the function for my sign up button which is all found in component SignIn.js :

```
const pressSignUp = () => {
    if (emailFormatCheck(email) && passwordFormatCheck(pass)) {
        try {
            emailSignUp(email, pass);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('HELLO');
            console.log(error);
        }
        navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
};
```

Here is the code for creating an account using firebase, found in a file called email-sign-up.js:

```
 import firebase from './fb';

const emailSignUp = (email, password) => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password);
};

export default emailSignUp;
```

I haven't gotten those logs to show up in `pressSignUp()` though. Is the catch not firing? Thanks for looking. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need an async function, on your page:

```
import {AuthContext} from '../navigation/AuthProvider';

const SignupScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const {register} = useContext(AuthContext);

// your input buttons here

<FormButton
        buttonTitle="Sign Up"
        onPress={() => register(email, password)}
      />
```

AuthProvider.js

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            if (e.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
              alert('Invalid Email Address');
            } else if (e.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
              alert('Incorrect Password');
            } else if (e.code === 'auth/too-many-requests') {
              alert('Too many attempts, try later.');
            } else if (e.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
              alert('Email not found, please create new account.');
            } else {
              console.log(e);
            }
          }
        },
        guest: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signInAnonymously();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```